# ¿Como agregar get o set al contructor? JAVA

Tags: java, get

Buenas estoy haciendo un sistema pero tengo un problema , quiero agregar un constructor en la clase venta que me reciba un email del cliente y id del producto por parametro , quiero hacer eso con los get  o set de las clases cliente y producto , pero me sale null cuando creo el objeto de venta y agrego esos datos por parametro

hice esto :

```
public class Venta {

    private Usuario cliente;
    private Producto producto;
    private int idVenta;


    public Venta(Usuario cliente , Producto producto) {
        this.cliente=cliente;
        this.producto=producto;
        this.idVenta=(int)(Math.random()*200)+1;

    }

    public Venta(String e , Integer idP) { //este es el constructor que quiero armar
        this.cliente.setEmail(e);
        this.producto.setId(idP);
        this.idVenta=(int)(Math.random()*200)+1;

    }



    public Venta(String nombre, String apellido, String email, String password,  Double precio,
            Integer punto, String descripcion) {
        this.cliente = new Cliente(nombre, apellido, email, password);
        this.producto = new Producto(precio, punto, descripcion);
        this.idVenta =(int)(Math.random()*200)+1;

    }

    public Usuario getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Usuario cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public Producto getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public void setProducto(Producto producto) {
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    public Integer getIdVenta() {
        return idVenta;
    }

    public void setIdVenta(Integer idVenta) {
        this.idVenta = idVenta;
    }

}
```

Comment: public Venta(String e , Integer idP) este constructor no esta recibiendo un objeto cliente por eso te da null

Comment: y que tendria que hacer ? crear el objeto adentro del constructor? o no hace falta?

Comment: pasarel un objeto cliente public Venta(String e , Integer idP,Cliente cliente)

Answer (score 0):

En tu clase Venta tienes unos objetos definidos:

```
private Usuario cliente;
private Producto producto;
```

Pero no los has instanciado. Osea, apuntan a null hasta que no hagas un new.

Tu otro constructor:

```
public Venta(Usuario cliente , Producto producto) {
    this.cliente=cliente;
    this.producto=producto;
    this.idVenta=(int)(Math.random()*200)+1;   
}
```

Ya recibe los objetos creados. Alguien hizo new de ellos antes de llamar al constructor de la clase Venta. Así que lo que haces es guardar una referencia a esos objetos en los de tu clase. Usando ese constructor no te da problemas.

Pero usando el otro:

```
public Venta(String e , Integer idP) { //este es el constructor que quiero armar
    this.cliente.setEmail(e);
    this.producto.setId(idP);
    this.idVenta=(int)(Math.random()*200)+1;
}
```

no instancias los objetos `this.cliente` ni `this.producto`, asi que al ejecutar `setEmail` o `setId` te dará una excepción.

Fíjate bien en lo que haces con `this.cliente` y `this.producto` en el último constructor porque ahí tienes la clave. Hace un new pasándole los parámetros que recibe. El problema es que en el constructor en el que te falla te faltan datos para crear los objetos. Así que o te inventas los que te faltan (con valores por defecto, por ejemplo), o ese constructor como tal no tiene sentido.

Comment: Pero el OP pregunta como puede evitar que le "salga null cuando creo el objeto de venta y agrego esos datos por parámetro" ?

Comment: Pues ya se lo he dicho, creando los objetos antes de hacer el set, como hace en el otro constructor.